# Dominated convergence theorem for $(1+u/\sqrt{n})^n e^{-u\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $$\int_{- \sqrt{n}}^{+\infty}(1+ \frac{u}{\sqrt{n}})^{n}e^{-u\sqrt{n}}du$$

the limit of this integral will be detrermined by the dominated convergence theorem

but, for the dominance we must prove that
$$\forall - \sqrt{n} \leq u \leq 0, ~~~n \ln (1 + \frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}) - u \sqrt{n} \leq \frac{- u^{2}}{2}$$
$$\forall  u \geq 0, ~~~n \ln (1 + \frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}) - u \sqrt{n} \leq - u + \ln(1+u)$$
How we can do it?

Comment: Are you trying to find the limit of this integral?

Comment: Are you sure it converges?

Comment: my essential question is how to get the two above inequalities?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1893922/dominated-convergence-theorem-with-f-nx-frac1-sqrt2-pie-sqrtnx-l

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach. It is easier to make the change of variables $\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}=t$ which gives

> $$ I=\int_{-1}^{\infty}\sqrt{n} (1+t)^n e^{ -nt }dt .$$

A second change of variables $1+t=y$ yields

> $$ I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\sqrt{n}e^{n} y^n e^{ -ny } dy. $$

Finally, we make the last change of variables $ ny=z $ which makes the problem to fall apart

> $$ I = {n}^{-n-1/2}\,e^n\int _{0}^{\infty }\!{z}^{n}{{\rm e}^{-z}}{dz} . $$

Now, the last integral is a well known function which is the gamma function $\Gamma(n+1)$ together with Stirling approximation

> $$ n! \sim \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2 \pi n},  $$

you can find the limit. The answer should be

> $$ I = \sqrt{2\pi}. $$

Comment: thanks, but my essential question is how to get the two above inequalities

Comment: how to prove the dominating function??

Comment: @salma: It is easier instead to deal with one of the above forms in my answer.

Comment: But the problem that I have found this question in an exercice where the function Gamma is given and the aim of the exercice is to give the Stirling approximation