# Proving $\left(1 + \frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n e^{-\sqrt{n} t} \le (1+t)e^{-t}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I would like to prove the inequality
$$\left(1 + \frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n e^{-\sqrt{n} t}  \le (1+t)e^{-t}$$
for $t > 0,n \in \Bbb N_{>0}$.

This is claimed in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/137001) answer, but I don't know how to proceed. I only know that $(1+\sqrt n t/n)^n \leq e^{\sqrt n t}$, so the LHS is bounded by $1$...

Comment: you can show that the LHS is a decreasing function of $n$

Comment: @SiXUlm : thank you for this idea, but how would you do it directly? I tried without success...

Comment: Another proof is here: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/stirling.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we set $n=z^2$ and switch to logarithms, the LHS turns into
$$ g(z) = z^2 \log\left(\frac{z+t}{z}\right) - t z = z \int_{0}^{t}\frac{z}{u+z}\,du-z\int_{0}^{t}1\,du = -\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{z}}\,du$$
that clearly is a decreasing function over $(1,+\infty)$ for any $t>0$.